# Using umbraco 7.x for webform projects

Tags: asp.net, umbraco, umbraco7

Is it possible or is it suitable to use umbraco 7.x for webform projects?

I'm a beginner in ASP.NET MVC and I'm learning about it, now.
Now I get a website project that I should do it immediately.
I just can do project with ASP.NET Webform, but I'll immigrate from Webform to MVC in the future.I want to have less problems when I decide to immigrate to MVC.Then I want to use Umbraco 7.x for my project in order to my plan.

Now, my question:
Is it possible or is it suitable to use umbraco 7.x for webform projects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer is yes, you can mix MVC and Webforms within an Umbraco 7 project.  The rendering engine is determined by the template.

If an MVC template is found then it will use MVC as the rendering engine, otherwise it will look for a .master template (in the masterpages folder) and if it finds one it will use Webforms

Comment: To follow up on this, you can choose a default (i.e. the type of template Umbraco will generate by default when you create a new one) by going to your umbracoSettings.config file (in the config folder), searching for "defaultRenderingEngine" and changing the value from "MVC" to "WebForms"

Comment: It seems Umbraco 7.6 has removed support for WebForms.